# Nodejs: See what keys exist in Couchbase DB

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Is there a way using the node js couchbase db driver to find all existing keys in the database? I just migrated clouds and now after loading the data all my get methods return:

```
{[CouchbaseError: The key does not exist on the server] message: 'The key does not exist on the server', code: 13 }
```

Is there an api call that I couldn't find in the documentation that just returns a list of document keys?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a primary index and query with N1QL.  The docs cover [doing a query](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/sdk/nodejs/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html), and it'd just be for `meta().id`